# Where do I find all the SE sites that support hats?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2012

So, hat season is here!  But I don't think all SE sites are participating.  Where do I find a list of the ones that are?

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [Leaderboard on Winterba.sh](http://winterba.sh/leaderboard) and you should see a list of all sites that are opted in or on which you *can* opt in!